How about the recursive code for "Find Zero" I've written?
Here's the problem:

Given an array nums, write a function that moves all 0s to the end of the array while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements.
Please note that the array must be modified in place without creating a copy of the array.

Does this code take linear time? If not, should I write the code in a more normal way using two pointers?
'''Recursively solve the 'Find Zero' problem without a new array created.'''

def Min_Zero(j, nums):
    while nums[j] != 0 and j < len(nums)-1:
        j += 1
    return j

def Min_Not_Zero(i, nums):
    while nums[i] == 0 and i < len(nums)-1:
        i += 1
    return i

# Swap the first zero element with the first non-zero element which is latter than the first zero element
def Swap_Zero(i=0, j=0, nums=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0]):
    n = Min_Zero(j, nums)
    m = Min_Not_Zero(n, nums)
    if m < len(nums)-1 and n < len(nums)-1 and m > n:
        nums[m], nums[n] = nums[n], nums[m]
        Swap_Zero(m, n, nums = nums)
    return nums

Swap_Zero()

I've successfully run the code. It's verified.

Don't define default function arguments using lists. It's gonna cause you a lot of problems.

Welcome to SO! What do you need help with exactly? I mean, what do you mean by "how about" and what's stopping you from figuring out the time complexity yourself? Check out [ask] for tips and [edit] to clarify.

Thank you, I'll change the default argument, In order to  see it faster I set the list as default. So in this case the normal way to  write the code makes more sense right?

Which end of the array do you have to move them to? There is a fairly simple O(N) way to move them all to the far end of the array by having an index and an outdex (which is only incremented when x[index] is non zero). Slightly harder if zeroes must come first.

It's worth noting that this code is not "Given an array nums". You would need to change the call to Swap_Zero(nums).

Yes, it's linear. (@matszwecja: On each iteration the functions Min_Zero and Min_Not_Zero start at the same index at which they ended in the previous run, so in total each iterates the array only once).

I've successfully run the code. It's verified.

No, it's not. You ran the code with one (or a couple of examples).
It breaks if you call it with [1, 0, 1].
The parameter i in Swap_Zero is unused.
The code is convoluted.
It more or less already implements the algorithm suggested by @Martin Brown, but in a way that is too complicated. You do not need recursion here.
@Martin Brown: Why should it be more complicated if the 0 have to come first? The situation is completely symmetrical. There is one set of characters that should be moved to the front. In one case it's all character except for "0", in the other case it is the single character "0".
This is the simplest code I could come up with. No guarantee, though, test it yourself ;_)
def move_zeros_to_end(nums):
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] != 0:
            if index != i:
                nums[index] = nums[i]
                nums[i] = 0
            index += 1



Two other small remarks, if you allow me: Please use Python naming style (lower_case function and variable names. Do not both change the array in place and return it. That is confusing for the caller.

Addressing people in an answer in response to comments they made will not alert them. Answers are not intended to react on comments (also because comments are temporal in nature). I would suggest to take those comment-reactions out of your answer and post them as comments where they belong.

Trying to develop a recursive solution just over-complicates matters.
All you need to know are how many zeroes there are in the source list which means that you can achieve your objective as follows:
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0]

nums[:] = [x for x in nums if x != 0] + [0] * nums.count(0)

print(nums)

Output:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Rationale:
Create 2 lists. First list is all of the non-zero elements and the other all the zero value elements. Combine the 2 lists and assign to the original address space.
Note:
This is identical to LeetCode problem #283

Such a pythonic coding!

"LeetCode problem #283" requires that you must do this in-place, without making a copy of the array.

@slago There is no copy made of the input list in this answer. I also submitted this solution on LeetCode and it was accepted.

@SIGHUP How can you create 2 new lists without allocating space proportional to the input size? That is not a in-place solution, as it is required.

@slago You have clearly misunderstood the brief. "Please note that the array must be modified in place without creating a copy of the array" There is nothing in the description to say that additional space cannot be used. The "array" is not copied

@SIGHUP It seems to me that you are not acquanted with the concept of what is an in-place algorithm. In computer science, an in-place algorithm is an algorithm that operates directly on the input data structure without requiring extra space proportional to the input size.

this solution iterates over the entire input twice

@SIGHUP creating a new two new arrays then copying those values into the original array is not an in-place algorithm.

@Mulan That may be so but LeetCode seems to like it so make of that what you will

This code is an adaptation @eekboom's code that avoids need to check for index collision -
def swap_zeroes(t):
  a = 0
  for b in range(1, len(t)):
    if t[a] != 0:
      a += 1
    elif t[b] != 0:
      t[a] = t[b]
      t[b] = 0
      a += 1

Alternative with match. Sometimes it's nicer to think in terms of what matches (==) instead of what doesn't (!=) -
def swap_zeroes(t):
  a = 0
  for b in range(1, len(t)):
    match t[a], t[b]:
      case 0, 0:
        pass
      case 0, v:
        t[a] = v
        t[b] = 0
        a += 1
      case _, _:
        a += 1

Here's a recursive equivalent. Note this will cause a stack-overflow error for large inputs (~1000 elements or more) -
def swap_zeroes(t, a=0, b=1):
  if b >= len(t): return
  match t[a], t[b]:
    case 0, 0:
      swap_zeroes(t, a, b + 1)
    case 0, v:
      t[a] = v
      t[b] = 0
      swap_zeroes(t, a + 1, b + 1)
    case _, _:
      swap_zeroes(t, a + 1, b + 1)

Each program is tested and produces the following output -
tests = (
  [],
  [1],
  [0,1],
  [1,0],
  [0,0],
  [0,0,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0,2,3,4,0,0,0,5,6,7,0,0,0,8,9],
  [1,2,3],
  [0,0,0,1,2,3],
  [1,2,3,0,0,0],
  [1,1,0,1],
)

for t in tests:
  print(t)
  swap_zeroes(t)
  print(t)
  print("---")

Output
[]
[]
---
[1]
[1]
---
[0, 1]
[1, 0]
---
[1, 0]
[1, 0]
---
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
---
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
---
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
---
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
---
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
---
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
---
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0]


Btw here's my tester that found the failing case for the earlier code. The new code passes.

thanks for sharing. sorted(p, key=bool, reverse=True) probably deserves a little more attention in this thread.

Meh, they seem to want linear time, and strictly speaking, that's not linear. (Btw I'm still hoping someone will post a correct answer to their main question, "Does this code take linear time?")

arr = [2, 0, 1, 2,5]

count = 0

for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] != 0:
        arr[count] = arr[i]
        count += 1

while count < len(arr):
    arr[count] = 0
    count += 1
    


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

A rework of your original code so that it can take normal arguments and be plugged into @mulan's testing loop:
def Max_Not_Zero(i, nums):
    while i < len(nums) - 1 and nums[i] != 0:
        i += 1
    return i

def Max_Zero(i, nums):
    while i < len(nums) - 1 and nums[i] == 0:
        i += 1
    return i

def Swap_Zero(nums, i=0):
    # Swap first zero element with first subsequent non-zero element 

    n = Max_Not_Zero(i, nums)
    m = Max_Zero(n, nums)

    if m > n:
        nums[m], nums[n] = nums[n], nums[m]
        return Swap_Zero(nums, n + 1)

    return nums

This should give you a better idea how your code compares to the alternatives being presented.  This does preserve the original list.
Although your algorithm moves in a linear fashion down the list, it stops and recalculates (i.e. recurs) after every swap, which is a loss of efficiency.

How much "loss of efficiency"?

What does "preserve the original list" mean? You do modify the original list.

@KellyBundy, by "preserve the original list" I mean that id() of the input list and id() of the returned list will be the same.  The elements of the original list are swapped but no new list is created.
